# Python BINANCE API Code Works But Actual Trade Isn't Done in Binance

Tags: python, cryptocurrency, binance-api-client

I am preparing my own binance bot.

I m trying to buy 200 unit TRX coin via api and and i have 19.96 USDT in my wallet.

TRX unit price is : 0.06195, so i am able to buy 200 TRX unit in binance app or web.
Min. buying count must be more than 10 USD and buying 200 unit for 12.39 USD.

My code looks like work.

Here is my API restrictions screenshot:
[image]

```
from binance.client import Client
import time
import asyncio
from binance import AsyncClient
from binance.enums import *
from binance.helpers import round_step_size
from decimal import Decimal as D, ROUND_DOWN, ROUND_UP
import decimal

api_key = 'xxxx'
api_secret = 'xxxxx'

client = Client(api_key, api_secret)

client.create_test_order(
    symbol='TRXUSDT',
    side=Client.SIDE_BUY,
    type=Client.ORDER_TYPE_MARKET,
    quantity=200,
    recvWindow=10000)
print('Buy: {}'.format(100))
```

However when i check my binance wallet, the trade isn't done. Any idea what was wrong?

Comment: Im not familiar with the API, but from a quick read and by looking at your code it seems that you use `create_test_order`, you might have to replace that by `create_order` to make a valid transaction.

Comment: @mnikley haha i didn't realise it :D my bad, thx for advice :) i will let you know the result

Comment: thx @mnikley the code block works now :)